# Error for public static double pow

Tags: static, double, public, pow

I am very new at Java so forgive me if I ask the stupid question.
I have an assignment where I need to calculate pow of two numbers (lets say it's 2.0^3) also I am supposed to use public static double pow() .
But for some reason I get the following errors:

for the Ecpipse it's- Error: Could not find or load main class exp.e

and for the DrJava-  Static Error: No method in static pow has name 'main'

```
class pow
```

{

```
 public static double pow( double x, long y )

 { 
       x = 2.0;
       y = 3;
       double exp  = Math.pow(x,y);
       return exp;
 }
```

}

I must be missing something very basic. But I already spent the significant amount of time on it and I can't figure it out. Could someone please point me out what am I doing wrong

Comment: *I must be missing something very basic.* Indeed. A main method (the entry point of your program), to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your `main` method.

Every program in Java starts by calling a `public static void main(String[])` method. Your code doesn't seem to have this method. You need to create one, for the program to run. All the other methods should be called from this `main`, or for some method called by `main`, or some method called by some method called by `main`. This is the so-called Call Stack, because the methods are "stacked" when called and removed from stack when they are over (hopefully by the `return` statement, such as in your method). When this stack uses too much memory, we have a "Stack Overflow" error - which, not by a coincidence, is the name of this very website.

Hope that helps.